# Could not find method classpath() for arguments on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, android-studio

when I run my code, I face this Error on the log:

The message says:

> ERROR: Could not find method classpath() for arguments
>   [com.android.tools.build:gradle:5.6.2] on object of type
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

could anyone help me?

Comment: It may be a trouble with dependencies, do you realize any problem in your Gradle file?

Comment: post your build.gradle file